writing cookie in middleware, but redirect page doesnt see it
im sending emails to users with some creds in URL, I then capture these creds in the middleware, verify creds against API, set cookies, then redirect to page to take action (like verify email or reset password). this approach is working locally, in my staging environment, but not in production. in production, it gets to the action page, doesn't see the user and redirects to login. whats stranger is the login page does see the cookies. below is some code on how I'm setting the initial cookie from my verify page and redirecting.
if (pathname.startsWith("/verify")) {
 const new_tokens = await attemptLoginLink({ id, token });
 if (new_tokens) {
      const response = NextResponse.redirect(
        type === "password"
          ? origin + CHANGE_PASSWORD_URL
          : origin + EMAIL_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS_URL
      );
      response.cookies.set({
        name: "session",
        value: new_tokens.accessToken,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "strict",
        maxAge: jwtExpiryTime / 1000,
      });

      response.cookies.set({
        name: "refresh",
        value: new_tokens.refreshToken,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "strict",
        maxAge: refreshExpirytime / 1000,
      });

      return response;
    }
  }

  const user = await getSession();
 // more code to refresh token if user cooie expired
 if (pathname.startsWith("/profile") && !user) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(origin + "/auth/login");
  }

any idea why cookies arent being read, in production, after I set them in middleware and redirect to a new page?
but then they are visible on the page after that??
"next": "14.2.14",
